# How many $three$-term Machin-like formulas using unit fractions and $\arctan \big(\frac{1}{239}\big)$ are there?

Tags: number-theory, trigonometry, pi

There are exactly ***four*** 2-term Machin-like formulas where the arctan argument is a ***unit fraction***, namely,
$$\begin{aligned}
\frac{\pi}{4} 
&=\arctan\frac{1}{2} + \arctan\frac{1}{3}\\
&=2 \arctan\frac{1}{2} - \arctan\frac{1}{7}\\
&=2 \arctan\frac{1}{3} + \arctan\frac{1}{7}\\
&=4 \arctan\frac{1}{5} - \arctan\frac{1}{239}
\end{aligned}$$

(*Updated question:*) Using a rather basic *Mathematica* code, I found ***twenty-four*** 3-term formulas using only unit fractions and the constraint that one denominator $d>100$. However, ***almost half*** use $d=239$, namely

$$\begin{aligned}
\frac{\pi}{4} 
&=4 \arctan\frac13 -4 \arctan\frac18-\arctan\frac1{239}\\
&=2\arctan\frac17+4\arctan\frac18+\arctan\frac1{239}\\
&=4\arctan\frac17+4\arctan\frac1{18}-\arctan\frac1{239}\\
&=8\arctan\frac18-4\arctan\frac1{18}+3\arctan\frac1{239}\\
&=4\arctan\frac14-4\arctan\frac1{21}-\arctan\frac1{239}\\
&=4\arctan\frac16+4\arctan\frac1{31}-\arctan\frac1{239}\\
&=6\arctan\frac17-4\arctan\frac1{57}+\arctan\frac1{239}\\
&=6\arctan\frac18+2\arctan\frac1{57}+\arctan\frac1{239}\\
&=12\arctan\frac1{18}+8\arctan\frac1{57}-5\arctan\frac1{239}\\
&=8\arctan\frac1{10}-4\arctan\frac1{515}-\arctan\frac1{239}\\
\end{aligned}$$

with the third to the last appearing [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_formulae_involving_%CF%80#Machin-like_formulae), the second to the last being [Gauss's Machin-Like formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GausssMachin-LikeFormula.html), and the last in [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Machin-LikeFormulas.html) (courtesy of Leibovici's comment).

> **Questions**:

1. Is the list above complete for $d=239$?
2. And why do so many formulas use $d=239$?

Comment: Have a look at http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Machin-LikeFormulas.html You will find seven of them.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: Thanks for the link. I'm doing a computer search right now, but it turns out Weisstein has already found a total of 105 solutions. It might be interesting to determine if there are in fact infinitely many (due to a parameterization).

Comment: Look at https://archive.lib.msu.edu/crcmath/math/math/m/m004.htm

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: I've updated the post with the results of my computer search. Interestingly, $d=239$ popped up a lot.

Comment: Could you provide the  Mathematica code ? May be, you could add it to the post since it is interesting.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici:It's too long to type. Essentially, I just used the _Do_ function to search for $$\tan\Big(\big(\tfrac{\pi}4-a\arctan(1/b)-c\arctan(1/d)\big)/e\Big)^{-1}=\text{Integer}$$

Comment: Could you e-mail it to me in a .TXT file ? I do not have MMa but I should like to play with it using my tools. May e-mail address is in my profile. Cheers.